# Writing a pre-compressed image using Libtiff / other libraries

Tags: opencv, jpeg, codec, image-compression, libtiff

**Task:** I am trying to create multipage tiff files at high speed, 4 pages each 4096 x 4096 8-bit bitmap. Each page needs to be compressed with a codec before, that results in minimum loss, before being written.

**What I am doing:** I am using Libtiff (Standard version, no IPP or GPU) to create these multipage tiff files and compressing each page using JPEG (quality- 95). I tried to use `TIFFWriteEncodedStrip()`, `TIFFDWriteEncodedTile()` and `TIFFWriteScanline()` and the CPU choked. In order to optimize the process, I am using my own JPEG compression method which is able to compress fast.

**Problem:** I am not able to write a tiff file with pre-compressed data. I am not able to use any `WiteEncoded..()` or `WriteRaw..()` methods in LibTiff.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a method in Libtiff or extensions written by third party that would let people to write pre-encoded data to a multipage tiff file ?
2. Is there a version of Libtiff, IPP or GPU based that I can use that will speed up my process ?
3. Or, are there other libraries available to write multipage tiff files that would solve my problems ?

   I am open to other compression codecs as well as long as it can save space with minimal loss.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you please show how to use "TIFFDWriteEncodedTile()" or "TIFFDWriteRawTile()"? I can't find any examples online...